# IMPORTXML: how to scrape NBA logos from a webpage (with Google Sheets)

Tags: parsing, google-sheets, import, html-parsing

**Webpage**: https://www.sportslogos.net/teams/list_by_league/6/National_Basketball_Association/NBA/logos/

**Tool**: Google Sheets.
Function: *importxml*

**Query**:
I want to retrieve the link of the NBA logos with *importxml*.

**Tries** (without any success):

```
//a[@title='Atlanta Hawks Logos']/@content

//a[contains(@title,'Atlanta')]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the logo based on **team_name**:

```js
=image(importxml(A$1,"//*[@title='"&A2&" Logos']//img/@src"))
```

[image]

If you need all the images in one go:

```js
=importxml("Webpage","//img/@src")
```